# Tauri - How can I read a file inside the project folder?

Tags: tauri

I use the Tauri JS on Ubuntu. I would like to read a csv file which is in the project directory.

```
/data/example.csv
/src-tauri/
/src
...
```

I activated the `fs` module, I tried different patterns

```
"all": true,
      "fs": {
        "scope": {
          "allow": ["$APP/**", "$APP/db/**", "$APP/data/**" ,"$DOWNLOAD/**", "$RESOURCE/**", "/data/**", "data/**"]
        }
      },
```

But when I try to read with the following code:

```
import { readTextFile } from "@tauri-apps/api/fs";

let filePath = "./data/example.csv";
console.log("File path:", filePath)
const promise = readTextFile(filePath);
promise.then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
})
```

I always get the following error:

```
[Error] path not allowed on the configured scope: ./data/profiles.csv
```

Answer (score 4):

write this

```js
import { resourceDir } from '@tauri-apps/api/path';
const resourceDirPath = await resourceDir();
console.log(resourceDirPath)
```

$ npm run tauri dev 
console log show this

**yourApp\src-tauri\target\debug**

$ npm run tauri build 
console log show this

**yourApp\src-tauri\target\release**

https://tauri.app/v1/api/js/modules/path/#resourcedir

Nerver forget this setting

```
 "fs": {
        "all": true,
        "scope": [
          "$RESOURCE/*"
        ]
      },
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding an explanation of the code you supplied.

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me. You need an additional `dir: path` option, when you call readTextFile. I used it with [Tauri - BaseDirectory](https://tauri.app/v1/api/js/enums/fs.BaseDirectory) and continue with the relative path. Maybe it works just with a filepath as well.

1. With await:

   ```js
   import {
     BaseDirectory,
     readTextFile
   } from "@tauri-apps/api/fs";

   export const readFile1 = async() => {
     try {
       const result = await readTextFile("file.txt", {
         dir: BaseDirectory.App,
       });
       console.log("result: " + result);
       return result;
     } catch (error) {
       console.log(error);
       return false;
     }
   };
   ```
2. With promise, adjusted to your example:

```js
export const readFile2 = async() => {
  let filePath = "data\\example.csv";
  let appPath = BaseDirectory.App;
  console.log("File path:", filePath);
  const promise = readTextFile(filePath, {
    dir: appPath,
  });
  promise
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
};
```

For completeness, my `tauri.conf.json` content:

```js
...
"tauri": {
  "allowlist": {
    "fs": {
      "all": true,
      "scope": [
        "$APP/*",
        "$DESKTOP/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  ...
```

If you replace the file with a wrong one "notThere.txt", the error will display the path in the console where it is looking. I had the same problem. You can open the console in the tauri app with (ctrl+shift+i) or right click.

For others, who try to get it work: you need to add the tauri-api to your project: `yarn add -D @tauri-apps/api`.

A [blog](https://www.matthewtao.com/blog/post/glipma-devlog-2/) post from matthewtao helped me a lot. He applies different methods from Tauri, like read/write file or create a directory with Tauri.

- github/[Glipma](https://github.com/matthewyingtao/Glipma) example from him using Svelte is awesome